# Pointer disappears when waking PC up from Suspend Mode

Tags: 17.04

Yesterday, I took an old computer and put Ubuntu on it. It works perfectly but when it goes to Suspend mode the pointer disappears and the only way I can fix it is to reboot the PC.

Please help.
Thanks!